# pickle module doesn't work for this simple code

Tags: python, pickle

when i run this code in Python 3.4.2(win7-64) it doesn't work! it creates file but nothing in it.(0 bytes)
I don't know what is the problem? Help- Thanks
Windo

```
import  pickle
f=open ("G:\\database.txt","wb")
pickle.dump (12345,f)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to close the file object that you have opened. So just add the line

```
f.close()
```

at the end and it will work.

As an alternative, you can also use the `with` statement to open the file, then it will automatically close the file for you when it's done:

```
import pickle
with open("G:\\database.txt", "wb") as f:
    pickle.dump( 12345,  f )
```

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: I just edited my answer to include that :)